# Cannot create BeerBarrel class and assign it to variable

Tags: java

I programmed an BeerBarrel class, however the creation of new BeerBarrels seems not to work properly. I seriously don’t get the mistake.

```
public class BeerBarrel extends FluidContainer{
private static int totalBarrels = 0, totalLiters = 0;

private BeerBarrel(String type, int liter) {
    naming = type;
    totalFluid_in_liter = liter;
    totalBarrels++;
    this.fluidContainerId = totalBarrels;
    totalLiters += liter;
}

public void tap(int liter) {
    this.totalFluid_in_liter -= liter;
    totalLiters -= liter;
}

public static int getTotalBarrels() {
    return totalBarrels;
}

public static int getTotalLiters() {
    return totalLiters;
}
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
public void run() {

BeerBarrel bf1 = new BeerBarrel("Pils", 80);
BeerBarrel bf2 = new BeerBarrel("Alt", 100);

BeerBarrel bf3 = new BeerBarrel("Koelsch", 50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor in BeerBarrel is private. Private constructors can not be accessed from outside the class.
The solution would be:

```
public BeerBarrel(String type, int liter) {​​​​​​
    naming = type;
    totalFluid_in_liter = liter;
    totalBarrels++;
    this.fluidContainerId = totalBarrels;
    totalLiters += liter;
}​​​​​​
```